# Screen lock engages while it's disabled

Tags: 18.04

Screen lock is off in the privacy settings, but it keeps on showing after the screen goes blank after 10 minutes.

I just want the screen to go blank after ten minutes without having to press esc every time I get back to using the PC.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and it's simply great, except for this little irritation.

Comment: No sorry, none of those two option worked at all.